# Need clarification on Snowflake questions

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I came across some sample questions for the Snowflake core certification exam and need opinion if my answers are correct or not.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I very much doubt that anyone on this site is going to mark 29 exam questions for you - and even if they did, how would you know their answers are correct? There are plenty of sites that provide exam questions + answers, so I suggest you use one if those. Udemy would be a good place to start

Comment: Yeah thats the thing I thought hard before posting this. Ideally I know stackoverflow is not the place to post such stuff. But the answers for these questions were different on those sites and I think those were incorrect. Hence I posted these as a hope to double check.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend to validate these questions against the documentation and try things yourself in Snowflake. This approach will ensure you actually know the correct answer through experience, and thus will be able to use it in your work later.